# andor2 package for python installation

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.7

I want to install andor2 package for python 3.7.
When I run pip install andor its exiting with error status 2.

### C:\Users\Anand>pip install andor
Collecting andor
Using cached andor-1.14.tar.gz (237 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: andor
Building wheel for andor (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5y_a8og\andor\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5y_a8og\andor\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-21e_ayh1'
cwd: C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5y_a8og\andor
Complete output (13 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
skipping 'andor2.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'andor2' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -I. -I.. -IC:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I/usr/lib64/python/site-packages/Cython/Includes -IC:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcandor2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\andor2.obj
andor2.c
C:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
andor2.c(244): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atmcdLXd.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

ERROR: Failed building wheel for andor
Running setup.py clean for andor
Failed to build andor
Installing collected packages: andor
Running setup.py install for andor ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5y_a8og\andor\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5y_a8og\andor\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cfl6hm5t\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\Include\andor'
cwd: C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5y_a8og\andor
Complete output (13 lines):
running install
running build
running build_ext
skipping 'andor2.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'andor2' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -I. -I.. -IC:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I/usr/lib64/python/site-packages/Cython/Includes -IC:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcandor2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\andor2.obj
andor2.c
C:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
andor2.c(244): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atmcdLXd.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5y_a8og\andor\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5y_a8og\andor\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cfl6hm5t\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Anand\Anaconda3\Include\andor' Check the logs for full command output.

What could be the issue? how to solve this?

Comment: I downloaded the package files from git and tried local install...

running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing andor.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to andor.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to andor.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'andor.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'andor.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
cythoning andor2.pyx to andor2.c
error: C:\Users\Anand\andor2.pyx

This is the error it is showing...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: C:\Users\Anand\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
      andor2.c(244): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atmcdLXd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

error: legacy-install-failure